# GIT: GitKraken vs SourceTree - что выбрать, или все в месте?

Tags: git, source-tree

Добрый день!

Для работы с гитом я раньше использовал **SourceTree**, а на новой работе нужно использовать **GitKraken**. Я пытался понять, в чем разница между ними, ну кроме интерфейса, но гугл разницы не показал.

На одном ресурсе предлагали использовать их вместе, но там же в каждом нужно клонировать репозиторий, правильно?

Подскажите - есть ли смысл использовать обе эти программы, либо можно только 1 какую-то из них использовать? Да и в чем разница между ними, кроме интерфейса?
Кроме того что кракен платный...

Спасибо

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Git под ними один и тот же. Наверняка вам кто-то пытается навязать свое личное мнение про "идеологически верный" выбор. Никакой разницы нет, какой именно софтиной вы будете пользоваться для работы с репозиторием, кроме личных предпочтений. Нравится платная софтина и дают корпоративную лицензию - отлично. Нет - работайте с тем, с чем удобно.

Но если все вокруг будут сидеть на другой программе, то есть риск, что с вашими возможными проблемами коллеги помочь просто не смогут. Поэтому, если опыта не много, то я бы рекомендовал начать работать на общих правилах, а потом, когда появится понимание, начал бы тюнить свой личный процесс.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! а чтобы использовать обе софтины, например, нужно 2 раза репозиторий клонировать, или можно их направить на 1 папку с уже склонированным репозиторием?

Comment: @LeonidZolotarov, Нет, достаточно склонировать репозиторий лишь однажды, а в каждой программе его лишь открыть. Попробуйте основы Git прямо в консоли, тогда получится легче отличать мух от котлет и вообще понимать, зачем эти программы нужны и что они могут сами по себе.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Спасибо, что вы в ответе не стали поддерживать холивар, а обратили внимание на принципиальные моменты, которые верны для всех инструментов.

Comment: Можно я к вам добавлю абзац про «но там же в каждом нужно клонировать репозиторий, правильно»? На целый ответ не тянет, но всё же важно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Если работать именно с gui не принципиально, то лучше пользовать консоль, тогда не будет зависимости от сторонних инструментов и доступных функций будет побольше =)

Как пример могу порекомендовать книжку по гиту:
https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2

или любые видео на Ютубе. Вот, например, парень понятно объясняет:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6RFFNCAd9w&list=PLU2ftbIeotGr_C-6t_lXH1Z3VgS5TLLdb